# Validation failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: and

Tags: java, server, exception, websphere, rational-rsa

When I am trying to enable administrative security in WAS server(RSA Ide) it throws this error:

Validation failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: internal cause is: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in your path `jre_install_dir\lib\security\cacerts` the installed certificated for this, if not add the client certificate in this path.

> javax.net.ssl.trustStore: File path of the truststore file. If you do
>   not use javax.net.ssl.keyStore to specify a client certificate, you
>   can use the truststore to install CA certificates and client
>   certificates. Default Value: jre_install_dir\lib\security\cacerts
>
> Example: C:\Program
>   Files\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\lib\security\cacerts

From [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRMWJ_6.0.0/com.ibm.isim.doc_6.0/installing/tsk/tsk_ic_ins_first_security_truststore.htm)